# Unhelpful Kind equality error at the start of file

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-kinds, constraint-kinds, polykinds

I get an error

```
app\Main.hs:1:1: error:
    Couldn't match kind `*' with `Constraint'
    When matching types
      b :: *
      (Set b, Set s) :: Constraint
  |
1 | {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
  | ^
```

I don't know why `b` and the constraint `(Set b, Set s)` are being matched?
I would expect the constraint to existentially quantify the type b but why would it be matching them?

I believe the last thing I changed before getting the error was adding OpOutcome to the class.

here is the code

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}


module Main where

import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Reflection (Reifies, reflect)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

main :: IO ()
main = print 5


class ((a,b)::Constraint) => HasCtxt a b
instance (a,b) => HasCtxt a b
class Determines a b | a -> b
instance Determines a b => Determines a b
type Set b = (b ~ b)

type OpLayout a = (forall s ctxt b. (OpCtxt a s b ~ ctxt, Determines a b, Determines a ctxt,Reifies s b) => ( HasCtxt ctxt (Reifies s b))) :: Constraint


data Stack a where
  Cons :: OpConstructor a -> Stack b -> Stack a
  Nil  :: Stack "NIL"


class  OpLayout a => OpCode (a::Symbol) where
  type OpCtxt a s b = (ctxt :: Constraint) |  ctxt -> s b
  type OpOutcome a :: *
  data OpConstructor a
  opValue :: Determines a s => Proxy s
  opValue = Proxy
  popOP :: OpCtxt a s b => Stack a -> (b :: *)
  evalOP :: OpConstructor a -> Stack x -> OpOutcome a

instance OpCode "load_val" where
  type OpCtxt "load_val" s b  = (Set s, Set b)
  type OpOutcome "load_val" = Stack "load_val"
  data OpConstructor "load_val" = forall b. LOAD_VAL b
  popOP stack = reflect opValue
  evalOP op stack = op `Cons` stack
```

edit: smaller version, thanks to Krzysztof Gogolewski

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

module Err where

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Determines b | -> b
class (forall (b :: *) (c :: Constraint). (Determines b, Determines c) => c) => OpCode
instance OpCode
```

Comment: Whoop, I didn't even know that `| -> b` was valid syntax, though I guess it makes sense! Nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a much smaller file that has essentially the same error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Test where

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Determines a b | a -> b

class  (forall ctxt. (Determines a a, Determines a (OpCtxt a)) => ctxt) => OpCode a where
    type OpCtxt a :: Constraint

instance OpCode ()
```

This gives:

```
test.hs:1:1: error:
    Couldn't match kind ‘Constraint’ with ‘*’
    When matching types
      OpCtxt () :: Constraint
      () :: *
  |
1 | {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
  | ^
```

(By the way, in the future, you should probably try to do some similar minization yourself before asking on here.)

It's certainly a bug that GHC reports the error with such unhelpful location information. However, there's now so few places for a problem to lurk that we can have a pretty good idea what's happening. The situation here is that we are asking for

```
Determines a a
Determines a (OpCtxt a)
```

with a functional dependency in scope that says `a` should be enough to work out the other argument to `Determines`. Well, we know `a` has `*`, because we're writing `instance OpCode ()` and `() :: *`; and we know `OpCtxt a` has kind `Constraint`, because we said so in the class declaration. So GHC gives up on trying to unify `a` and `OpCtxt a` before it even gets started -- they don't have the same kinds, so can't be equal!

The only trick you need left to see why you get the exact error message you do is to stick `()` for `a` everywhere (because that's the instance we're trying to write).

Translating back to your setting: you ask for

```
Determines a b
Determines a ctxt
```

where we know `b :: *` because it appears as the second argument to `Reifies :: k -> * -> Constraint`, and we know `ctxt :: Constraint` because we said so in the `OpCode` class declaration. So the functional dependency can't possibly work out right. Then you get the error you saw by putting `OpCtxt "load_val" s b` for `ctxt`, and then reducing to `(Set s, Set b)`.

Comment: Thanks for the incredible answer, you guys do a great job on GHC and I hope I can get better at asking these questions.